# Running C++ DLL with rundll32 - Missing entry

Tags: c++, dll, rundll32

So I'm trying to use rundll to test and run my C++ written DLL , and i've followed the guidelines here and on other sites and the entry point looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport)  void CALLBACK entry(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But the rundll process prompts me with an error message box saying "Error in C:\path\to\DLL Missing entry: entry"

Attempted execution command: "rundll32 C:\path\to\DLL, entry".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can double-check by running Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL to see the actual exported name.  Which right now is *not* `entry`, as the error message tells you.

You need to prefix `extern "C"` to the declaration to disable C++ name mangling.

Good enough for a 64-bit executable, but that turns it into `_entry@16` if this is a 32-bit DLL, still not quite good enough to keep rundll32 happy.  Use Project + Add New Item, Code node, pick the "Module-Definition File (.def)" item template.  And make it look like this:

```
EXPORTS
entry = entry
```